# How to Implement Console View in Pure Eclipse 4 RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have created a part in e4xmi which should act like a console view. How to make this part as a console like view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for a console view or launching programs in a pure e4 RCP so you are going to have to craft everything yourself.

If you are using `ProcessBuilder` or `Runtime.exec` to launch a program you just need to set up threads to read the output of the program and send it to a part.

The part could use something like the JFace `SourceViewer` to display the output.

Comment: thanks Greg.Is there any Sample implementations available?

Comment: Not that I know of.